# X must be a string of length 1

Tags: r, string

Estoy intentando crear un bucle para hacer web scraping con el paquete rvest y realmente funciona cuando solamente descargo una página pero mi idea es descargar todas las páginas que necesite y no ir una por una.

El código que he creado para hacer la descarga es este:

```
col_link <- "https://www.infocif.es/ranking/ventas-empresas/espana"
col_page <- read_html(col_link)
col_table <- col_page %>% html_nodes("table#tablaranking") %>% html_table()
col_table
```

Este código para una sola página va perfecto, no hay problema.

Para el bucle cree esto:

```
ids <- c(2,3)
files <- paste0("https://www.infocif.es/ranking/ventas-empresas/espana?pagina=",ids)

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  col_page <- read_html(files)
  col_table <- col_page %>% html_nodes("table#tablaranking") %>% html_table()
}
```

En ese caso, cogí solamente 2 ids para comprobar que funcionaba el bucle pero aquí es dónde está el problema.

Ejecuto y la respuesta es el error mencionado: **Error: `x` must be a string of length 1**.

He probado cosas como el Vectorize pero no me sirve de nada, sigue dando el mismo error.

Si alguien puede echarme un cable sería genial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que en el bucle, el índice "i" no se le esta especificando en que variable irse moviendo, es decir, solo te falto agregar lo siguiente:

```
  col_page <- read_html(files[i])
```

Además, te sugiero que estos resultados se vayan guardando en una lista, para que tengas cada resultado de la iteración guardado.

El código podría quedar así:

```
lista_col_table = list()

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  col_page <- read_html(files[i])
  col_table <- col_page %>% html_nodes("table#tablaranking") %>% html_table()
  lista_col_table[i] = col_table
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Bastian, funciona perfectamente!